# Dropzone : drag and drop is not working in firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, dropzone.js

I am using http://www.dropzonejs.com/ to add images to gallery. This is working fine in Google chrome,but in Firefox, I am not able to drag and drop images.
I have checked dropzone.js and tried to add e.preventDefault but still not able add image by dragging.

please tell me what can i do and how can i resolved this problems.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).